# Killing process on Ubuntu with os.system() issue

Tags: python, linux, os.system

I try to send command from python shell to `Ubuntu OS` to define process existed on particular port and kill it:

```
port = 8000
os.system("netstat -lpn | grep %s" % port)
```

Output:

> tcp  0  0  127.0.0.1.8000  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  22000/python

Then:

```
os.system("kill -SIGTERM 22000")
```

but got following trace

`sh: 1: kill: Illegal option -S`

For some reason command can not be transferred to OS with full signal `-SIGTERM`, but only with `-S`. I can simply kill this process directly from `Terminal`, so seems that it's `Python` or `os` issue... How can I run `kill` command using Python? 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using

```
import signal
os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill).

you could also use `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT`, which corresponds to the CTRL+C keystroke event.

Comment: Thank you! `os.kill(22000, signal.SIGTERM)` works fine

Answer (score 6):

`os.system` uses `sh` to execute the command, not `bash` which you get in a terminal. The `kill` builtin in `sh` requires giving the signal names without the `SIG` prefix. Change your `os.system` command line to `kill -TERM 22000`.

[EDIT] As @DJanssens suggested, using `os.kill` is a better option than calling the shell for such a simple thing.